# numberOfRowsInSection not overriding Attributes Inspector

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsrangeexception

In `Swift 2`, working on a `UITableView` that will dynamically create cells based on the contents of a dictionary. The dictionary has 38 entries. When I manually set the Table View Section to have 38 rows in the Attributes Inspector, everything works as expected.

However, this isn't ideal, and I'd rather use `numberOfRowsInSection` to get the count of my dictionary and create rows/cells that way. When the Att Inspector is set to 1, I get an out of bounds error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftyJSON
import UIKit

class OurTableViewController2: UITableViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    var labels = [String: UILabel]()
    var strings = [String]()
    var objects = [[String: String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        //gets data that will be used for cells
        let urlString = "http://handheldart.org/api/tags/"
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
                let json = JSON(data: data)
                parseJSON(json)
            }
        }

        //menu button at top left of screen
        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }

    }

    //creates array 'objects'
    func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
        for result in json.arrayValue {
            let id = result["id"].stringValue
            let tagURL = result["url"].stringValue
            let tagName = result["name"].stringValue
            let obj = ["id": id, "tagURL": tagURL, "tagName": tagName]
            //print (tagName)
            objects.append(obj)
        }

         tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    //create number of rows based on count of objects array
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print ("OBJECTS COUNT")
        print (objects.count) //prints 38
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

        let object = objects[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text =  object["tagName"]!

        return cell
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You aren't conforming to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

Comment: why are you trying to set the row count in your storyboard if your data is all dynamic?

Comment: I originally created the cells there just to test the design, & am now retroactively moving away from storyboard. It was a simple miss, just forgot to set TableView to dynamic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because you marked your tableview's content property as "Static Cells". You need to set your tableview's content as "Dynamic Prototypes". You can do that from the tableview Attributes Inspector -> Choose "Dynamic Prototypes on the first property "Content".

[image]